# multiple types of user in same community portal

Tags: community, login, roles

Is it possible to use the same community portal for the different type of users?
If yes, how can we distinguish them after login?

We have different types of user, one is Rider & Other is Driver.
1) A rider can add ride
2) A driver can search ride & accept it.

So if I have to use check if logged in portal user is driver or rider, what should I do? I need to show different dashboard (& pages) to both.

Please inform if anyone knows how to achieve above

Comment: what exactly differentiates your user types? do they have different profiles?

Comment: We can assign different profile if needed, but not sure if it's the only or any other option is available.

Comment: Actaully user is created by apex triggers, so we can have option to set any field if needed.
We can assign different profile if needed, but not sure if it's the only or any other option is available.
If we use profile, will it be good?
or 
we can add custom field to user object & use that field to distinguish

Please give your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The usual method of distingushing different community user types is using a [Profile](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.community_templates.meta/community_templates/rss_profiles.htm) for them, this can be used to:

1. Control Object and Field access
2. Set page variations in the Lightning Community builder
3. Set different page layouts in Salesforce if using normal object pages
4. If using Topics then these can also be selected by profile

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have multiple types of users in a community, both by license type and by [community user profile](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_customize_login_page.htm&type=0). You can also use the [Expid_value](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.externalidentityImplGuide.meta/externalidentityImplGuide/external_identity_dynamic_extend_endpoint_expid.htm) or Experience Id to customize what a user sees via [dynamic branding](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_customize_login_dynamic.htm&type=0) or other content.